# Conditionally showing span in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following..

```
<span class="error">@Model.ErrorMessage</span>
```

The problem is that the css for error class makes a yellow box which is showing up even when the ErrorMessage is empty.

Is there  a best practice for handling this?  I was thinking of an @If (using Razor) but it seems odd to have logic like that in my view.

Comment: ShaneC there is nothing wrong with having a simple if statement to control the span visibilty. Why are you hestitating? Why is it 'odd'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it seems odd to have logic like that
>   in my view.

View will have view logic in it. MVC is not MVP or MVVM where any code behind is discouraged. I believe having `if` in the view is quite normal.

Alternative is to have the model (view model) have a property which will be set as CSS class of the `span`. If error is empty, CSS class could have `display:none;`

Comment: +1, and honestly, what could be more readable then `@if (predicate) { <span>...</span> }`?

Comment: thanks!  I had the same thought after I posted but wanted to see what the community came up with.